# Nonstandard inequality with parameter and absolute value

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, absolute-value

The given inequality is $|x^2-ax+1|<3(x^2+x+1)$. The question is:

For which values of $a$, every $x$ is a solution?

I am trying to solve it by making the graphics of the two sides of the inequality but have hard time doing so.

Comment: $a=-1$ is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the cases $$x^2-ax+1\geq 0$$ and $$x^2-ax+1<0$$
In the first case you have to consider the inequality:
$$x^2-ax+1<3(x^2+x+1)$$ and so on.